# Get request headers through postman programatically

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, postman

I'm trying to scrape this real state website: https://www.metrocuadrado.com/ using the python library requests.

The problem I'm facing is that a simple request gives me a forbidden status code:

import requests

```
url = 'https://www.metrocuadrado.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r)
403
```

When I'm using Postman to make this request it works and give me this as the correct params:

```
import requests

url = "www.metrocuadrado.com"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'incap_ses_1345_434661=U9U2AdMp+jJQ7opPnGaqEkixJ2EAAAAAH421XYzlPOjxBvHbjDdbDg==; visid_incap_434661=pfcTeEkUQI+PMJLNMKGO0XmIJ2EAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADXG52+V+y5UkqEQzQ3z2Af'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Then I copy this on my editor and works, the problem is that the cookies change nearly every 5 minutes and I need to scrape all the properties on the site. I'm in search of some tool/library that allows me to send the request through postman, get the cookies and then use requests.

As an option, I tried with selenium `get_cookies()` but these cookies are different from those given by postman and don't work with requests

Comment: The  url you are trying to scrape is incorrect because it doesn't contain data.

Comment: @Fazlul, nope, the page is correct, try to make a postman request and you'll see. Or maybe in your country it's not available

Comment: This [url](https://www.metrocuadrado.com/apartamento/venta/nuevo/?search=form) contains data, just an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@David Lopez I'm getting working output.

CODE:

```
import json
import requests


    url = "https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search?realEstateTypeList=apartamento&realEstateBusinessList=venta&realEstateStatusList=nuevo&from=50&size=50"
    headers = {
        "Referer": "https://www.metrocuadrado.com/apartamento/venta/nuevo/?search=form",
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
        'x-api-key': 'P1MfFHfQMOtL16Zpg36NcntJYCLFm8FqFfudnavl'
    }
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd never think of using the referer header